# Mapping map values in Java using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a map, `Map<String, Map<String, String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();` that I would like to remap to get it's values, so that I get as a result `Map<String, String>`.

Is it possible to do the mapping using stream API?

I have solved the problem using a `for` loop but I'm interested if that could be done using streams.

My solution:

```
   Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

    myMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        result.putAll(v);
    });
```

What I want is to get all the values from `myMap` and put them in a new Map.

Comment: So you're just throwing away the *keys* of the initial map , and flattening the inner maps. What about **uniqueness** of the keys (are you ok with overriding values)?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yes that is what I am trying to do. The keys are all unique.

Comment: In short, if you want to address the problem using a stream, you need to flatten the entries of the nested maps. E.g. `Map<String, String> result = myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap( Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue ));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain there are no duplicate keys, you can do it like this.

```
Map<String, String> res = myMap.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(value -> value.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
```

If there may be duplicate keys between the inner maps, you will have to introduce merge function to resolve conflicts. Simple resolution keeping the value of the second encountered entry may look like this:

```
Map<String, String> res = myMap.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(value -> value.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v2));
```

Basically, stream the values, which are `Map`s, flatten them to a stream of entries and collect the entries in a new Map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten the entries of the nested maps which can be done using either `flatMap()` or `mapMulty()`.

And then apply `collect()` with the minimalistic *two-args* flavor of Collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) passed as an argument. It would be sufficient since you don't expect duplicates.

Here's an example using [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)):

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        
Map<String, String> res = myMap.entrySet().stream()         // stream of maps
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream()) // stream of map entries
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,  // key mapper
        Map.Entry::getValue // value mapper
    ));
```

Example with Java 16 [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) used for flattening the data:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        
Map<String, String> res = myMap.entrySet().stream()   // stream of maps
    .<Map.Entry<String, String>>mapMulti((entry, consumer) -> 
        entry.getValue().entrySet().forEach(consumer) // stream of map entries
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,  // key mapper
        Map.Entry::getValue // value mapper
    ));
```